# JUnit Tests not letting me know if test passed or failed

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I'm running some junit tests and usually green or red bar shows indicating if it passed or not. However, I've been getting this
[image]
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: red bar and green indicate that you passed or not, you can click and say run it as JUnit test in menus. try it.  does it show any error? (in Failure trace)

Comment: First test still running

Comment: but it is s simple code. I don't think that get much time but your picture show that it is running. I think question is not complete. do you get result eventually or not?

Comment: nope its been like that since i posted it and i tried running it in the menu and still the same result.

Comment: Then defintely you have a bug, which is an infinite loop

Comment: good call @HimanshuBhardwaj